# How to make the code output something else when an integer is entered for string in Python

Tags: python

Can you please explain how to make the code say something else like "Wrong" when an integer is entered instead of a string
eg:

```
name = ("Enter you name: ")
if name == int:
    print("Wrong")
```

I tried to use the code i used above but the program just skipped it.

Comment: That's not valid python. Can you please fix up your quotation marks and indenting so we can find your problem easier?

Comment: That code would not skip anything, it would throw any of a number of errors. Please ensure your code is an accurate representation of what you used. I'd also suggest spending some more time with tutorials to become more familiar with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add input to ask the user for their name. Then check if it is a number.

```
name = input("Enter you name: ")
if name.isnumeric():
    print("Wrong")
```

It may be better to account for all non alphabet characters. Then, try to check if the input is alphabetical.

```
name = input("Enter you name: ")
if not name.isalpha():
    print("Wrong")
```

I would also suggest putting the code in a loop to keep asking until it is correct.

Comment: From all of the answers, I think that this is the most simplest so thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        print("Wrong")
    except ValueError:
        print(s)
```

Comment: This doesn't ask the user for input and the OP's code is missing that part too. I'm not sure they're up to the stage of defining their own functions.

Comment: Also, using an exceptional result to validate input seems... odd. The user did the "correct" thing when this code throws a `ValueError`.

Comment: I didn't make the specifications for the problem, I just tried to help.

Comment: That's from your point of view, if you get to fix the problem and manage to understand why and how, I think it's enough, I don't think it's normal as you said having an except as positive, but for this chase it works fine for approximately 3 lines of code and reusable for other situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements to find out if the particular integer string is found in the input function. You will use the input function to store the name, but this will automatically evaluate to a string. So, used an if statement to look for any integer (that will be stored as a string in the input function). If any are found, you will get your error message.

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")

if '1' in name:
    print('Wrong')

if '2' in name:
    print('Wrong')

if '3' in name:
    print('Wrong')

if '4' in name:
    print('Wrong')

if '5' in name:
    print('Wrong')

if '6' in name:
    print('Wrong')

if '7' in name:
    print('Wrong')

if '8' in name:
    print('Wrong')

if '9' in name:
    print('Wrong')

if '0' in name:
    print('Wrong')
```

Each time a name is entered, each if statement will check to see if an integer has been stored as a string within the error message. If it is not stored, no error message will occur. If an integer is stored as a string, and error message will occur.

Comment: I really want to believe you don't use code like this; you'd go mad from copy/paste. Also, it's really inefficient because every single condition will be checked, regardless of whether or not a previous condition was `True`.

Comment: Also, `hell0` does not mean that I entered an integer, but this code would still throw an error.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you're saying. Think you have a typo in your second comment. "hell0" ?

Comment: Are you saying that 0 isn't an integer? That's a zero, not a letter in the code. I copied and pasted it in from the .py.

Comment: `"hell0"` is a string that happens to contain `"0"`. It's still a string, but this code will consider the entire input to be an int, which is not the case. It was no typo.

Comment: Okay. Then the question is who cares? Based on what the OP wanted, it shouldn't matter. If a user enters a real first name or last name, it's irrelevant because there will not be a number in the name. Maybe if they have a username program, which they didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `input` function in order to take input from the user.
`name = input("Enter you name: ")`

You can then check if the given information is convertible to an int (since input will always store the value as a string) using a `try except` statement. This will try to cast name to an int. If it succeeds, you know, it is an int. Otherwise, it is not an int.

`try:
    int(name)
    print("Wrong")
except ValueError:
    pass`

Alternatively, you can use the `isalpha` builtin function (which is probably more simple) to ensure that name only contains alphabetical characters:

`name = input("Enter your name: ")
if not isalpha():
    print("Wrong")`